# Jquery - what is most efficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very simple Jquery.

But I'm trying to see if one is better than the other, for memory, performance, or best practice.

This is the simplified table row.
I need to get either the `ROW ID` or the `ID` number from the field name stripping the field name from it.

```
<tr id='1'>
<td><input id='fieldA_1'></td>
<td><input id='fieldB_1'></td>
<td><input id='fieldC_1></td>
</tr>
```

So clicking into `fieldA_1` I could do either :

```
id = (this.id.replace('fieldA_',''))
```

or

```
id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
```

Which is better ?

Comment: those statements appear to be doing totally different things?

Comment: They do. One gets the ID from the TR (1) the other gets the ID of  the current field and removes the text to leave 1. So they both return 1. I'm try to see if one is better to use.

Comment: You can't use the first one (get the tr id) for the get id input case so..

Comment: But they do different things? Describe better? Neither is any worse than the other, they just do something that the other doesn't.

Comment: Each row has a unique ID. Each input within the cells on the row have a unique ID which ends with the rows ID. TR ID =`1` Cell A ID = `fieldA_1`
When I click into an input I want to know the Rows ID. So is it better to get the TD ID, or read the current cells ID and remove the unneeded text. ?

Comment: well, considering that it would be a quite bad practice to choose `1` as an id, you would need to do a similar replace for your second solution with a proper id.. For the first solution, you cannot replace generically `fieldA_` because each one has a different letter. I would pick the first though, slighly modified to work generically

Comment: @Kaddath thanks this code is only posted as an example. The actual ID's are based on GUID strings returned from a MySQL Database. The code I'm using is generic and will remove the text regardless of which input I click. This was more about what is the better method.

Comment: Just add a data attribute on the inputs. Something like "data-parent-id". Or any name that actually has a semantic meaning in the given context. No fiddling around, and it's nice and easy to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to get ID of input fields.

This is the right choice.

```
id = (this.id.replace('fieldA_',''));
```

I have implement this in my design with hundreds of controls and it works fine.

There isn't much difference when it comes to check performance, but still using this could save time to look around which is the closest tr when you have large number of controls on your page.

Comment: Why is that one better? This seems a totally arbitrary choice. They both work. There is very little in it from a performance point of view. You've basically just picked one.

Comment: I picked this because  I have used it extensively in my application and it never caused performance issue. Everyone has their right to put opinion here I believe.

Comment: Well, not really, SO is about [facts not opinions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/opinion-based-questions)

Comment: it would need a little test of course, but the other solution would appear slower at first look, because it needs more DOM operations

Comment: Thanks, this make more sense to me as its working with the locally retrieved values and not looking back for the `TR`

Comment: @Liam My opinion are facts which I implemented and experienced my friend :)

Answer (score 0):

The performance of the first method would be better as the usage of native Javascript is way better than jQuery, however, the performance difference is so little it doesn't matter anything. Just take which one you like more.

Only if you would use lots of jQuery code you could see a difference.